# Is there any way to handle wiremock scenarions manually?

Tags: wiremock

I'm using wiremock (rodolpheche/wiremock) for local stubbing. I want to get one of two stubs without any dependency to qyery or params. For example:

1. I call `GET http://foo.bar/identifier/{id}` (id is always same)
2. I need to get one of two mocks, depending on my process:

- good `{ "status": 0 }`
- bad `{"status": 999, "errors": [{"error": 1}, {"error": 2}] }`

Can this be done using any wiremock features?
For now i'm replacing a stub file in wiremock, but i want this to be automated somehow...

Comment: How are you determining `good` vs `bad`? What would differentiate the request so that WireMock would know to return good or bad? Is it just a process of "return good once, then return bad once, then good once, etc."? Or just randomly return?

Comment: I consider to have an external handler, that i can turn and the good mocks can be switched to bad.

Comment: Whatever external handler you have, if it is attached to your request, you can just have two separate stubs or mappings with matches for whatever that handler is. 
Otherwise, you can arbitrarily return a good vs. bad by just having them alternate within a scenario, or setting up some sort of response transformer to randomly return a good or bad response.

Comment: The thing is, that i can't attach it to request. Both good and bad requests should be equal, but somehow i need to switch good <-> bad with any available features of wiremock

Comment: If you want to have a consistent pattern of switching between good/bad, using http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/#scenarios to alternate state will probably achieve what you want it to do. If you'd rather have the good/bad responses be returned at random, you'd need to supply a response transformer that could determine what response to send on it's own. http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#response-definition-transformation